# ReactNative : How to design UI support all devices iOS and android

Tags: user-interface, react-native

I am developing react native app. I wanted to know about design screens that is automatically adjust to iOS and android devices. For example we are using auto layout for iOS apps which gives consistent view for all iPhones and iPads.

I am little bit confused about designing screens for android and iPhones. I know how to design UI for Native platform that is consistent for all devices.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create UI for both Android and IOS devices using the same js file.

Mainly u need to have a good idea about flexbox. It is the base of creating responsive UI for compatible all devices. Follow below tutorials and get a good idea about flexbox and design responsive UI

- https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox
- https://medium.com/the-react-native-log/a-mini-course-on-react-native-flexbox-2832a1ccc6

and You can find a good example of components https://github.com/jondot/awesome-react-native here.